# New to this, want to install Cairo Desktop

Tags: installation, cairo-dock

The command that I typed into Terminal was

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cairo-dock-team/ppa
```

It then says to enable PPA in list of repositories, and gives more commands to enter. After entering those, it says that I have held broken packages. What does this mean, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to install Cairo Dock is to start the Software Centre and search for Cairo, this will install the software as it should be. Then you can set it up how you want it set up, this nearly bought me to tears :)

Once it is set up and running and as you want it to be, if you want to play with Terminal, take a look at some of the commands that are available to you [here](http://ss64.com/bash/)

Answer (score 0):

You would need package of "compiz" too ( in Ubuntu 12.04 ) ?

(and compiz-fusion can be nice too.)

Here is explained for Ubuntu 13.04 :

http://hackyogi.com/how-to-install-cairo-dock-in-ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail/

and this here is easier :

http://www.unixmen.com/installing-cairo-dock-3-2-1-in-ubuntu-13-04/